# Determining number of states for Discrete Hidden Markov Model used as Classifier

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model, discrete-data

I want to train a discrete HMM on two different datasets containing user clickstream data, to classify new user sequences. The datasets contain 41 different observations (41 different API calls), and are split into two sets of sequences for two different types of users. I'll classify new users based on the highest likelihood predicted when feeding them into my two trained HMMs, according to a method from this paper: https://www.labs.hpe.com/techreports/2016/HPE-2016-62.pdf

How should I best determine the number of states for my HMM, or could someone give me a rough estimate to start with? The only thing relevant for this use case is giving an accurate likelihood for a new sequence belonging to the dataset the model was trained on. Implementation info: I'm using the hmmlearn python library.